# Can I create private eos blockchain without using RAM trading?

Tags: ram, resources

I would like to have a private network of servers that produce blocks and do not need to restrict resources.

Answer (score 1):

EOSIO by default has unlimited resources for users until you load the system contract.  The bios contract is under the control of the account eosio by default as well which is the key pair that comes in the config.ini.

You can read more about these contracts [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/boot-sequence).

You can also see the difference in API calls once the system contract is loaded [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference).

Comment: If I don't use [bios boot sequence](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/bios-boot-sequence)  steps and don't create  `eosio.system` then  which one feature  of eosio is disabled ?